# how to bind a datasource to a different type property?

Tags: c#, winforms

in the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BindingSourceSimpleTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class Color
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Red { get; set; }
            public int Green { get; set; }
            public int Blue { get; set; }
        }

        public class Obj
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Color { get; set; }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var colors = new List<Color>();
            colors.Add(new Color { Name = "Black", Red = 0, Green = 0, Blue = 0 });
            colors.Add(new Color { Name = "Blue", Red = 0, Green = 0, Blue = 255 });
            colors.Add(new Color { Name = "Red", Red = 255, Green = 0, Blue = 0 });
            colors.Add(new Color { Name = "Magenta", Red = 255, Green = 0, Blue = 255 });
            colors.Add(new Color { Name = "Green", Red = 0, Green = 255, Blue = 0 });
            colors.Add(new Color { Name = "Cyan", Red = 0, Green = 255, Blue = 255 });
            colors.Add(new Color { Name = "Yellow", Red = 255, Green = 255, Blue = 0 });
            colors.Add(new Color { Name = "White", Red = 255, Green = 255, Blue = 255 });

            var objs = new List<Obj>();
            objs.Add(new Obj { Name = "Sun", Color = "Yellow" });
            objs.Add(new Obj { Name = "Grass", Color = "Green" });
            objs.Add(new Obj { Name = "Blood", Color = "Red" });
            objs.Add(new Obj { Name = "Sky", Color = "Blue" });
            objs.Add(new Obj { Name = "Hair", Color = "Black" });
            objs.Add(new Obj { Name = "Snow", Color = "White" });
            objs.Add(new Obj { Name = "Rose", Color = "Red" });

            listBoxObjs.DataSource = new BindingSource(objs, null);
            listBoxColors.DataSource = new BindingSource(colors, null);
            comboBoxObjColor.DataSource = new BindingSource(colors, null);

            textBoxObjName.DataBindings.Add("Text", listBoxObjs.DataSource, "Name");
            comboBoxObjColor.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", listBoxObjs.DataSource, "Color");
            textBoxColorName.DataBindings.Add("Text", listBoxColors.DataSource, "Name");
            textBoxColorRed.DataBindings.Add("Text", listBoxColors.DataSource, "Red");
            textBoxColorGreen.DataBindings.Add("Text", listBoxColors.DataSource, "Green");
            textBoxColorBlue.DataBindings.Add("Text", listBoxColors.DataSource, "Blue");

            listBoxObjs.DisplayMember = listBoxColors.DisplayMember = comboBoxObjColor.DisplayMember = "Name";
        }
    }
}
```

and the following form UI:

[image: Form1]
<sub>(source: [persiangig.com](http://hamidi2.persiangig.com/image/910404_BindingSourceSimpleTest_UI.png))</sub>

1. i see that the sun is black! why?! after a deeper look i found that the items in the list of colors are of type Color while the Color property of an object is of type string.
2. how can i make the Color property of an object be shown correctly in
   the combobox?
3. if i fix this, changing the combobox selection updates this property of an object correctly too?
4. if i fix this, does sun gets yellow? :)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a reference to your color object in your Obj list.  It has a Color property that is string, but there is no relationship to the Color objects in the Color list.

```
    public class Obj
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public BindingSourceSimpleTest.Color Color { get; set; }
    }
```

Also, your classes should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for the databinding to work properly:

```
public class Obj : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private string name;
  private BindingSourceSimpleTest.Color color;

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName) {
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
  }

  public string Name {
    get { return name; }
    set {
      name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
  }

  public BindingSourceSimpleTest.Color Color {
    get { return color; }
    set {
      color = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Color");
    }
  }
}
```